# Find $a$ in $(a+b)\log a=c$?

Tags: logarithms

Find $a$ in $(a+b)\log a=c$

I have no idea how to do this. None of the basic log rules can solve this as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Manthanein either

Comment: I do not think that there is a solution (even using special functions).

Comment: I go with claude leibovici

Comment: No chance I give you unless we know something more.

Comment: What do $a,b$ and $c$ represent?